# Mikro-ORM nested collection type safe access

Tags: mikro-orm

I am unable to access properties of a nested loaded entities. I have the following structure

`Treatment OneToMany TreatmentCycle`

`TreatmentCycle ManyToOne Physician`

`Physician ManyToOne User`

`User ManyToOne Country`

I need to map this to another view model for presenting but I am unable to map `treatmentCycle->physician->user` properties

Code:

```
const treatment = await this.em.findOne(Treatment, id, {
  populate: [
    "diagnosis",
    "physician",
    "physician.user",
    "country",
    "medication",
    "treatmentCycles",
    "treatmentCycles.physician",
    "treatmentCycles.physician.user",
    "treatmentCycles.physician.user.country",
    "treatmentCycles.physician.profession",
    "treatmentCycles.physician.hospital",
    "treatmentCycles.medicationRegimen",
    "treatmentInterruptions",
  ],
});
```

When trying to map here result the following `TS2339: Property  user  does not exist on type  { id: string; } & Reference<Physician>` although I loaded in the relation previously. Same error applies for the `hospital` and `profession`

```
this.treatmentCycles = treatment.treatmentCycles.getItems().map((cycle) => {
  return {
    physician: {
      id: cycle.physician.id,
      userId: cycle.physician.user.id,
      fullName: `${cycle.physician.user.firstName} ${cycle.physician.user.lastName}`,
      email: cycle.physician.user.email,
      profession: cycle.physician.profession.identifier,
      hospitalIdentifier: cycle.physician.hospital.identifier,
      country: {
        id: cycle.physician.user.country.id,
        code: cycle.physician.user.country.$.code,
        name: cycle.physician.user.country.name,
      },
    },
  };
});
```

Am I missing something here or is there another way to do it?

**EDIT**

Entity definition for Treatment

```
@Entity({
  tableName: "treatment",
  repository: () => TreatmentRepository,
})
export default class Treatment extends AggregateRoot<Treatment, "id"> {
  [EntityRepositoryType]?: TreatmentRepository;

  @ManyToOne(() => Country, { ref: true })
  country!: Ref<Country>;

  @Enum({
    items: () => AvailableTreatmentStatuses,
    array: false,
    default: [AvailableTreatmentStatuses.ONGOING],
  })
  status!: AvailableTreatmentStatuses;

  @Property({
    type: "date",
    nullable: false,
    fieldName: "start_date",
  })
  startDate!: Date;

  @Property({
    type: "date",
    nullable: true,
    default: null,
    fieldName: "end_date",
  })
  endDate: Date | null = null;

  @Enum({
    items: () => AvailableTreatmentEndReason,
    array: false,
    default: null,
    nullable: true,
    fieldName: "end_reason",
  })
  reasonEnded: AvailableTreatmentEndReason | null = null;

  @ManyToOne(() => Diagnosis, { ref: true })
  diagnosis!: Ref<Diagnosis>;

  @ManyToOne(() => Medication, { ref: true })
  medication!: Ref<Medication>;

  @ManyToOne(() => Physician, { ref: true })
  physician!: Ref<Physician>;

  @OneToMany(() => TreatmentCycle, (treatmentCycle) => treatmentCycle.treatment)
  treatmentCycles = new Collection<TreatmentCycle>(this);

  @OneToMany(
    () => TreatmentInterruption,
    (treatmentInterruption) => treatmentInterruption.treatment
  )
  treatmentInterruptions = new Collection<TreatmentInterruption>(this);

  @Property({ persist: false })
  prescriptionsCount!: number;

  @Property({ persist: false })
  interruptionsCount!: number;

  constructor(payload: {
    countryId: string;
    status: AvailableTreatmentStatuses;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate?: Date | null;
    endReason?: AvailableTreatmentEndReason | null;
    diagnosisId: string;
    medicationId: string;
    physicianId: string;
  }) {
    super();
    if (payload.endReason && !payload.endDate) {
      throw new UnableToCreateNewTreatmentException(
        "Cannot add ended treatment without an end date"
      );
    }

    if (!payload.endReason && payload.endDate) {
      throw new UnableToCreateNewTreatmentException(
        "Cannot add ended treatment without an end reason"
      );
    }

    this.status = payload.status;
    this.startDate = payload.startDate;
    this.endDate = payload.endDate;
    this.reasonEnded = payload.endReason;
    this.country = Reference.createFromPK(Country, payload.countryId);
    this.diagnosis = Reference.createFromPK(Diagnosis, payload.diagnosisId);
    this.medication = Reference.createFromPK(Medication, payload.medicationId);
    this.physician = Reference.createFromPK(Physician, payload.physicianId);
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your entity definition look like? You are apparently misusing the `Ref` type.

Comment: @MartinAdámek added my entity definition. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `Reference` wrapper (`Ref` type), your relations are mapped to it instead of the underlying entity. This means that to access them, you need to use one of the ways to access the wrapped entity. There are several ways to do it:

1. since you have populated the relation, you should have a type-safe getter under `$` symbol

```
-cycle.physician.user.firstName
+cycle.physician.$.user.$.firstName
```

2. alternatively, you can use `Reference.load()` which is async and ensures the relation is loaded

```
-cycle.physician.user.firstName
+(await (await cycle.physician.load()).user.load()).firstName
```

3. when you know it's loaded but it's not properly typed (with the `Loaded` type), you can use `Reference.unwrap()` which is sync and only gives you the underlying entity without checking its loaded state.

```
-cycle.physician.user.firstName
+cycle.physician.unwrap().user.unwrap().firstName
```

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/next/guide/type-safety#reference-wrapper

Comment: I tried with the $ signs and I get the following error: 

TS2339: Property  $  does not exist on type  { id: string; } & Reference<Physician>.

EG this line fullName: `${cycle.physician.$.user.$.firstName} ${cycle.physician.$.user.$.lastName}`.

Comment: That means you broke the `Loaded` typing on the way, maybe you have some abstraction over the code you provided here? It will work if the types are correct, your `em.find` call should resolve to something like `Loaded<Treatment, 'treatmentCycles.physician.user.country'>` (there will be much more strings in the second type arg, exactly the same as you put into the `populate` option).